# SOAP with SpringBoot: Soap request addressed to wrong URI is magically redirected to other endpoint impl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, url-routing

I'm implementing SOAP WS services with Spring Boot.
To be able to filter requests based on the request URI, I want to provide different Endpoint implementation at different URI mappings.

To do so, I register both mapping with the servlet registration bean first:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*", "/special/*" );
    }
```

and then I register my Endpoint for each mapping:

```
@Bean(name = "serviceA")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition caseDocumentWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema caseASchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CaseAPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(CaseAEndpoint.NAMESPACE_URI);
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(caseASchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
}


@Bean(name = "serviceB")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition caseDocumentBkkWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema caseBSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CaseBPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/special");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(CaseBEndpoint.NAMESPACE_URI);
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(caseBSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Now, the undesired effect I see is that when I send a request with the payload for service A to the URI of service  B, e.g. with curl:

```
curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @caseARequest.xml http://localhost:8081/special/
```

it is handled by CaseAEndpoint implementation even though that is not registered (with setLocationUri) to handle it.

Thus, the plan to use the request URI to filter requests nd secure the endpoints does not work.

Any hint on what I'm missing or I need to add?

(As a workaround I added check in the endpoint impl based on the request URI using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().toUriString().contains("special")`) but that's not how it should be and not what the API suggests, right?

Comment: `setLocationUri` doesn't limit anything. The message dispatcher routes to the correct endpoint regardless of the URL/URI. The payload of the soap message (or action depending on the contract) is the thing used for routing NOT the url. If you want those to be really seperated, register 2 `MessageDispatcherServlet`s and each have its own configuration.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, thanks for your reply! 
I thought that this would be an option, but I couldn't find out how an ServletRegistrationBean and the DefaultWsdl11Definition Beans are linked together.
Is it just by being located in the same WsConfigurerAdapter ? And is it valid to have multiple @ EnableWs @ Configuration classes extending the WsConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: You will need to explicitly configure the `MessageDispatcherServlet` instances with their own application context. You will need to do some more manual setup. But do you really need this?